# Understanding why missing serial port I'm receiving data from usb

Tags: python

I've a device which is supposed to send data via a usb connection. When I connect my laptop via usb to this device and open a terminal I get sone weird characters and are printed as a command line. However I haven't configured anything.

If I try to connect to the device via serial port initializing it I cannot know which port is? Plugging ang unplugging the device shows no difference in the result of:

```
>ls /dev/*
```

Which seems the device is not detected, but as I said in the command promp or even if I use any other application, it is as if I was writing, but random characters

Does anyone k ow why does it happen?
How can I set communication characteristics to be able to connect to the device at a certain baud-rate?

The idea is to get data via Python.

Lots of thanks  ;)

Comment: Sounds like this device appears as a keyboard, rather than a serial port.  You didn't really expect any detailed help without even identifying this device, did you?

Comment: @jasonharper i was thinking the same. That the device seems to be recognised as a keyboard. Is there anything I can do to be able to capture its data and display it correctly? In theory it is a serial communication at 11500bps.

Comment: To capture data from a keyboard-like device, you'd use an ordinary entry field in a GUI app, `input()` or `raw_input()` for a CLI app.  There's probably a way to read it directly via the HID (Human Interface Device) driver, to keep its data separate from your actual keyboard, but I'm not familiar with the details.  Is this thing a CueCat barcode scanner, by any chance?  Those sent encrypted data (which sounds like what's happening in your case), and I believe the only solution ever found was a hardware mod that disabled the encryption.

Comment: Indeed I've just tried issuing ' lsusb' and there appears an extra device when pluggin in the external device as 'Bus 001 Device 038: ID 13ec:ac02 Zydacron'. Any ideas how can I manage to read data from this device?

Comment: It is a pressure therapy device. IT is supposed to send some ID and usage data at start up. It is not encrypted at all. The weird characters are really ascii regular just with no meaning due to bad synchronisation I guess.  I've tried some mac tools like Cool Term but they only list the wireless and bluetooth communication ports to be configured and connected. It doesn't see the device connection. :/